# Moving breakpoints in gdb

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to change the location of an existing GDB breakpoint?

I've set one on a particular line, and then added a condition to it. I would like to move it to a different line number, but retain the condition without having to destroy it and retype the condition.

I'm using GDB 7.5 on RedHat Enterprise Linux 5 64bit.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to do this.

It would be a nice addition, but nobody has implemented it yet.

You can use "save breakpoints" and then edit the result and source it.  This may be handy if the condition is very complicated.

Comment: Thanks, this seems the best way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Maybe `info break` is sufficient for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
break +offset
break -offset
    Set a breakpoint some number of lines forward or back from the position at which execution stopped in the currently selected frame.
```

(see http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_29.html#SEC29)

Comment: This makes a new breakpoint at a spot relative to where the inferior is stopped -- it doesn't move an existing breakpoint.